# serve an ashx page when an xml page is requested

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, rss, ashx

I have a .ashx file generating xml for both our rss feed and our sitemap. Our new SEO guy is telling us that the ".ashx" extension is harming us (for example, insisting that the existing "sitemap.ashx" file should be called "sitemap.xml", and the rss feed is "site.rss").

The organization I work for has pretty much lumped me with the hosting as well as the developing, and hosting isn't something I have a lot of experience of (I get by, but not an expert).

I know this is likely to be something in IIS such that requests for one thing get served another thing, but can someone give me a quick nudge in the right direction? I am having trouble even coming up with something to google right now!

EDIT: In this instance it's IIS7 and ASP.net 3.5

Comment: Please specify which versions of ASP.NET and IIS you are using, then I can make a better recommendation.

Comment: I think the SEO guy is wrong. The "extension" on a URL doesn't matter, what does matter is the content-type returned by the request.

Comment: @Brian: You may be right. But Google specifies `sitemap.xml`, and I think it's better to be safe than sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you'd want to expose/serve `http://foo.com/site.rss`, but actually execute `http://foo.com/bar.ashx`.

For [IIS7 , implement the URL Rewriting module with "Rule with rewrite map"](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/498/rule-with-rewrite-map---rule-template/).

Try this in your web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
<rewriteMaps>
    <rewriteMap name="StaticRedirects">
        <add key="/site.rss" value="/bar.ashx" />
    </rewriteMap>
</rewriteMaps>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 2):

no rewrite needed, you can have can configure the .ashx to respond to .rss or .xml in the web.config. you can always add query string parameters to respond to different logic.

```
<system.web>
    <httpHandlers >
        <add type="[ashx class name]" verb="*" path="*.rss"/>

    </httpHandlers>
```

...ect

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called "[URL Rewriting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine)" and while IIS doesn't provide quite out of the box, there are ways you can achieve it.

With Apache, you had mod_rewrite. With IIS (starting with version 7) which I presume you have you have *Modules*. Take a look at: [IIS URL Rewrite Module 2](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/737/url-rewrite-module-2/)

And if you're looking for more information or you're planning to roll-your-own, have a look here: [URL Rewriting in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx).

If your hosting the website on a shared hosting server you may not be able to install a custom module in IIS but you may be able to deploy it as part of your application.

Answer (score 0):

[IIS URL Rewrite 2.0?](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite)

BTW, it's usually installed & set up on shared hostings such as godaddy.com or discountasp.net, so you'll only need to write the config.

Answer (score 0):

If you're lucky enough to be using ASP.NET MVC you can relatively easily add redirection through the routes table in the global.asax.

From memory, you add a route like so:

```
routes.MapRoute(
"XML Reroute",
"specificname.xml",
new { controller = "Home", action = "Reroute" });
```

This would capture any requests for specificname.xml and they'd go to a controller called home, with an action of reroute which you could just redirect to your handler or move your handler code to.

**-Edit-**
That said, I'd probably go for the static routing option offered by p.campbell.